# How can I select the next caster group in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I have a big group of units selected, and two or more of the unit types can cast spells, how can I switch groups without de-selecting my units?

Comment: you might want to add Starcraft 2 into the title as well as the tag

Comment: @mfg: I figure they'll look at the tags when they don't find the obvious missing information in the title...

Comment: But it searches better if it's in the title too. Also people scanning questions can find that answer easier. Updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key. You will go to the next group of units. <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will go the opposite direction (so, previous group of units)

Comment: I'll assume this works... I just remember having this problem in beta, but I haven't had the chance to pick up a retail copy yet! (I'm on vacation..and here I am thinking "i cant wait to get back home so I can play some sc2")

Comment: Just a comment - it works the same way in Warcraft III, the previous Blizzard RTS.

Comment: Note that Shift+Tab is also the Steam Overlay hotkey.  If you're using Steam (as I am) you may want to consider remapping that (or remapping StarCraft's keys).